# How set two pageblock-Elements parallel in Visualforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I want to set two pageblock-Elements parallel with Visualforce. How can I do that?

```
<apex:page>

<apex:pageblock title="titleA" id="blockA">

</apex:pageblock>

<apex:pageblock title="titleB" id="blockB">

</apex:pageblock>

</apex:page>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

That's really a CSS question I'd say, about floating divs next to each other, using CSS for page layout etc. [It's been asked on SO numerous times.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=div%20next%20to%20each%20other) Wrap them it into an `<apex:outputPanel>`, play with float:right etc and you should be good to go.

If you want a pure Visualforce solution and aren't comfortable with CSS you can render them into a table. There's whole philosophical debate about how [tables shouldn't be used for layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) though ;)

[`<apex:panelGrid>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_panelGrid.htm) should be simplest to use in that case.

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
        <apex:pageblock title="titleA" id="blockA">
        </apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageblock title="titleB" id="blockB">
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to set the width of this two columns (like left column 70% and right column 30%). 
How can I do that.